# Getting Data Specific to Logged in user

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix

I need to list logged in users active leads,and allow paging and selectable sorting, I cant use the grid because of the layout requirement.

I have been searching the web for the last 2 days and cant find any viable solution

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
var query = db.Query("SELECT a.listingId, a.datetime, c.details, c.buycommercial, c.buyindustrial, c.buyretail, c.buyland, c.tencommercial, c.tenindustrial, c.tenretail, c.tenland, c.investor, c.developer, d.companyname, d.firstname, d.lastname, d.tel, d.cell, d.email FROM dbo.tblactivebroker a JOIN dbo.tblActiveListing b ON a.ListingId = b.ListingId JOIN dbo.tblListings c ON b.ListingId = c.ListingId JOIN dbo.tblContact d ON c.crmid = d.id WHERE b.active = 'True' AND a.ActiveBrokerID = @0",brokerid);
```

Comment: What's the problem? What is not happening that you want to happen (or what is happening that you want not to)?

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear, I cant sort or add anything after a.ActiveBrokerID = @0",brokerid), is there a better way of getting the data specific to the user

Comment: I still don't understand your query. Want you improve your query filters or display the result with paging and sorting?

Comment: I want to be able to add paging and sorting to the query.

Comment: For paging without to use WebGrids look at this [article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/150/Web-Pages-Efficient-Paging-Without-The-WebGrid)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about extending the query, you can use a string.Format.

Example:

```
var query = db.Query(string.Format("SELECT a.listingId, a.datetime, c.details, c.buycommercial, c.buyindustrial, c.buyretail, c.buyland, c.tencommercial, c.tenindustrial, c.tenretail, c.tenland, c.investor, c.developer, d.companyname, d.firstname, d.lastname, d.tel, d.cell, d.email FROM dbo.tblactivebroker a JOIN dbo.tblActiveListing b ON a.ListingId = b.ListingId JOIN dbo.tblListings c ON b.ListingId = c.ListingId JOIN dbo.tblContact d ON c.crmid = d.id WHERE b.active = 'True' AND a.ActiveBrokerID = {0} AND a.listingId = {1} ORDER BY a.ActiveBrokerID", brokerId, listingId))
```

However, it is 2012 and a better approach would be to use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) and [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx).

Comment: That's a horrible SQL injection prone approach.

Comment: @MikeBrind I agree, that's why I suggested using an ORM technology.

Comment: @mez You don't need an ORM. The Database helper in WebMatrix accepts parameterised queries.